# DAX error with type text values - Pay Terms

Tags: powerbi, dax

Team,

I get the DAX comparison operations do not support comparing values of type text with values of type integer error when using this formula:

Z - Term Type = if('Sage_SQL_AR_InvoiceHistoryHeader_CAN+US_Combined'[Z -Inv. Pay Terms]=0,"",if('Sage_SQL_AR_InvoiceHistoryHeader_CAN+US_Combined'[Z -Inv. Pay Terms]=30,"Net 30",if('Sage_SQL_AR_InvoiceHistoryHeader_CAN+US_Combined'[Z -Inv. Pay Terms]=45,"Net 45")))

I tried adding 'value' and couldn't get it to work. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks so much,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is occuring as
`'Sage_SQL_AR_InvoiceHistoryHeader_CAN+US_Combined'[Z -Inv. Pay Terms]` has data types `STRING`. Please make sure that you change the data type, so that expression can make the comparison.

```
Z - Term Type =
IF (
    'Sage_SQL_AR_InvoiceHistoryHeader_CAN+US_Combined'[Z -Inv. Pay Terms] = 0,
    "",
    IF (
        'Sage_SQL_AR_InvoiceHistoryHeader_CAN+US_Combined'[Z -Inv. Pay Terms] = 30,
        "Net 30",
        IF (
            'Sage_SQL_AR_InvoiceHistoryHeader_CAN+US_Combined'[Z -Inv. Pay Terms] = 45,
            "Net 45"
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I had my column in as a text and not decimal! Thank you so much!